# Is NSNetService only works with .local domain?

Tags: ios, macos, bonjour

I have a code [CocoaHTTPServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer/blob/master/Core/HTTPServer.m) which publishes service using Bonjour. And tt uses NSNetService for this.

It works fine (both on OS X and iOS) if you define domain ".local". However, if you define anything else, it doesn't publish a service and it doesn't call a delegate that it didn't publish the server.

I investigated this and found following info.

Documentation from [NSNetService class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNetService_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> This class and the NSNetServiceBrowser class use multicast DNS to
>   convey information about network services to and from your
>   application.

Documentation from [Bonjour domain names](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Articles/domainnames.html)

> On Bonjour systems, local. is used to indicate a name that should be
>   looked up using an IP multicast query on the local IP network.

Do I understand correctly that NSNetService class can work only with .local domain and can't work with wide-area bonjour (different domains)?

P.S. If I am not missing anything, I plan to contact Apple, because it's strange to have an argument with just one correct value and all other incorrect (and not reported through any errors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSNetService` does work with domains other than `local.`.

Before publishing your service, use [NSNetServiceBrowser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNetServiceBrowser_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSNetServiceBrowser) and `- (void)searchForRegistrationDomains` to find suitable registration domains.

Apple's **NSNetServices and CFNetServices Programming Guide** contains a section about this including sample code: [Browsing for Domains](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Articles/BrowsingForDomains.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001275-SW7).

Comment: How can I assign ip address to nsnetservice?

Comment: @user2801184 see [NSNetService publish](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnetservice) method. If you need more detail, please can you [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).